# Doing task between Multiprocessing python

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing

I want use multiprocessing library to parallelize the computation. If you comment line 5 and 9 and uncomment line 11 we can run this code in serial fashion.

My dataframe is very big and taking lot of time so I want to use multiprocessing.

This is what i am trying

```
def do_something (df):
    return df

def main(df,df_hide,df_res):
    p = Pool() # comment to run normal way
    for i in range(0,df_hide.shape[0]):
        
        df = df.append(df_hide.iloc[i,:])
        df = p.map(do_something,df) # comment to run normal way
        
        #df = do_something(df) # uncomment to run normal way
        
        df_res.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[-1,0] 
        
    return df_res
        
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
    df_hide = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,5,6]})
    df_res = pd.DataFrame({'z':[0,0,0]})

    df_res1 = main(df,df_hide,df_res)
    print(df_res1)
```

Excepted output it will come if I run it normally

```
   z
0  4
1  5
2  6
```

This gives me nothing It freezes the cmd. Any way still if I run it I don't think I will get expected results. As I have to do something after ever process. Can you please suggest how to parallelize this above code using multiprocessing.

Comment: what are you trying to do? copying column 'a' into column 'z'? Would be good to have a better example. Anyways, the second argument of `map` should be an iterable, in this case it's a dataframe...

Comment: Yes I am just copying column 'a' into column 'z' if just doing something in my real scenario just letting you know I will be needing these column values. Ohh how can I change my df to a iterable, I mean how can i pass my data that to my function?

Comment: If you can provide a better example I can try to help you. You can parallelize on the rows or columns. So if you have 4 cores you can process 4 rows (or 4 columns) at the same time instead of 1. In your example `do_something(df)` cannot be parallelized because it doesn't take as input a single row (or column).
Anyways, pandas has powerful methods to perform vectorized computations, if you manage to show what you want to do, then a solution can be proposed.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd   

def do_something (df):
    return df

def main(df,df_hide,df_res):
    for i in range(0,df_hide.shape[0]):
    
        df = df.append(df_hide.iloc[i,:])
        df_res.iloc[i,0] = df.iloc[-1,0] 
    
return df_res
    
if __name__ == '__main__':   
    df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3]})
    df_hide = pd.DataFrame({'a':[4,5,6]})
    df_res = pd.DataFrame({'z':[0,0,0]})

    df_res1 = main(df,df_hide,df_res)
    print(df_res1)
```

Comment: it will give you that output which you want.

Comment: I wan to run the same code in multiprocessing using all the cores of my system. My real dataframe is very huge it takes lot of time for computing hence I want to improve the computation for the same code you did serially.